# JqPlot - Strange Behaviour in Line chart when ticks are present

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqplot, linechart

This is my chart without ticks this is how I get my data:

```
var data = [@string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(h => h.HeartRate))];
```

[image: Heart Rate over distance (distance in X-Axis is not yet prepeared]

Now If I want to put in the X-Axis the distance I use this:

```
var data= [@Html.Raw(string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(pair => "[" + "'" +  pair.DistanceMeters.ConvertToKm() + "'" + "," + pair.HeartRate + "]")))];
```

And this is the result, check the first part of the chart:

[image: Wrong Start!]

This is how I'm setting my chart:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnResetHeartRateZoom').show();

        var data = [@Html.Raw(string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(pair => "[" + "'" +  pair.DistanceMeters.ConvertToKm() + "'" + "," + pair.HeartRate + "]")))];

        @*var data = [@string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(h => h.HeartRate))];*@
        var HeartRatePlot = $.jqplot('HeartInformation', [data],
            {
                seriesDefaults: { lineWidth: 1.0, },
                title: "@Resources.HeartRate",
                axesDefaults: { labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }, //Render de los textos.
                series: [{ showMarker: false, fill: true, fillAndStroke: true, color: '#FF0808', fillColor: '#FAC5C5' }], //Para no mostrar markers.
                axes:
                {
                    xaxis: { autoscale: true, label: "@Resources.Distance", pad: 0, tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                    yaxis: { autoscale: true, label: "@Resources.HeartRate [bpm]" },
                },
                highlighter: { show: true, sizeAdjust: 1.5 },
                cursor: { show: true, zoom: true }
            });

        $('#btnResetHeartRateZoom').click(function () { HeartRatePlot.resetZoom(); });
    </script>
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

PS: distance is in meters, I convert the tick to KM by dividing it by 1000.

Comment: Does pre-sorting the data make a difference?

Comment: I didn't try that... however in this scenario I wont be able to do it...

Comment: You can't just add some sorting on to that LINQ chain?